# Reading from Plist array Crashes Simulator but not in Xcode Console

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios-simulator, plist

I'm a newbie and have been stuck on this for hours.

I am trying to use PickerView selected integers to:
- p1: select path to array plist
- p2: select object at index of loaded array

I am testing path switching for 2 plist root = array files, when the picker makes a selection in the Simulator, it crashes, but the console NSLog outputs the correct value for the right plist and object at index value.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong? I don't understand why the simulator crashes, I have checked the XIB connections.

```
 #define person1 0
 #define person2 1 

     - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
              didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
               inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

            if ((component ==person1) || (component == person2)) { 
                    int p1; 
                    int p2; 
                    p1=[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:person1];         
                    p2=[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:person2]; 

            NSString* subPath = [[NSString alloc] init];

            switch (p1) {
                    case 0:
                        subPath = @"data0";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        subPath = @"data1";
                        break;
                    default:
                        NSLog(@"error");
                        break;
                }

            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:subPath ofType:@"plist"];
            NSArray *p1Array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
            NSString *resultsMessage = [[NSString alloc] init];
            resultsMessage = [p1Array objectAtIndex:p2];
            NSLog(@"%@", resultsMessage);
            result.text = resultsMessage; //Outlet = UITextView

            [p1Array release];
            [path release];
            [subPath release];
            [resultsMessage release];


                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't release any of those variables, because they were all created with methods that return autoreleased objects. Please read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Also, you can change `NSString* subPath = [[NSString alloc] init];` to `NSString *subPath = nil;`, otherwise you're leaking a string.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved the problem! the objects were released incorrectly. Is it better to avoid autorelease objects and stick to alloc/release as much as possible?

Comment: It generally doesn't matter, you just have to be careful sometimes (like if you're doing a lot of stuff in a loop, you should set up an autorelease pool to make sure things get released often enough). Also, if this answered your question then you can mark it as the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. Thanks :)